# ActiveRecord methods(find_by, find etc) not working when using use_transactional_fixtures = true in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, transactions, rails-activerecord

I am trying to move from `use_transactional_fixtures = false` to `use_transactional_fixtures = true` on my ROR application.
Many cases are failing after setting use_transactional_fixtures = true in RSpec config.
On further digging I came to find that the Active record query were not reading from transactions.

Example

```
   before(:all) do
     @user = User.first
   end
...
   describe 'POST #create' do
    context 'with valid params' do
      it 'creates a new HighScore' do
        post :create, high_score: { game: 'Test Game', score: 200, user_id: @user.id }
        parsed_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
        expect(@user.high_scores.find_by(id: parsed_response[:highscore_id])).to be_instance_of(HighScore)
      end
    end
  end
```

users table data before test starts

| id | first_name | last_name | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test | Account | test123@gmail.com |

high_scores table before test starts

| id | game | score | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | One | 100 | 1 |

The issue with this is `@user.high_scores.find_by(id: parsed_response[:highscore_id])` returns

```
nil
```

But the expected response is:-

```
#<HighScore id: 2, game: "Test Game", score: 200, created_at: "2022-04-11 10:36:39", updated_at: "2022-04-11 10:36:39", user_id: 1>
```

HighScore.all returns the value which is persisted in database before the test started i.e

```
#<HighScore id: 1, game: "One", score: 100, created_at: "2022-04-07 10:36:39", updated_at: "2022-04-07 10:36:39", user_id: 1>
```

The controller methods are all working and there is no issue with respect to creation of object.
These cases were working fine when transactional_fixtures were set to false.

```
Versions
Rails 4.2.11.3
ruby 2.6.9
RSpec 3.7
  - rspec-core 3.7.1
  - rspec-expectations 3.7.0
  - rspec-mocks 3.7.0
  - rspec-rails 3.7.2
  - rspec-support 3.7.1
```

I need someone to help me out on what is the cause that queries are not getting executed on transactions but rather on tables.

Comment: The use of `before(:all)`  here is a really big code smell. Use `let` or `let!` instead and set up the examples in isolation. If any of the examples here where to mutate `@user` it can lead to test order dependency issues and unreliable tests.

Comment: Here it is very likely actually break the code as the transactional fixtures are per example and you're only doing the query once for the entire example group. Its also unclear here how you're creating the user. If you're using ActiveRecord fixtures you should use something like `users(:one)`.

Comment: To add to @max 's comments: your question indicates a misunderstanding of how transactional fixtures work. If you're using transactional fixtures correctly, then every table in the database should be empty at the start of every test. Your `before(:all)` would always retrieve `nil` here, because there are no users. 

You also want to avoid before/after :all with transactional fixtures turned on, as these hooks happen *outside* of the transaction. This will pollute your test database and screw up all future tests until the database is cleared.